# Safari get wrong coords on jquery offset after transform rotate

Tags: jquery, safari, offset

I rotate element by `transform: rotate`, and then set `offset(top:XXX, left:YYY)` to this element.
It works perfectly in Chrome and FF, but Safari just calculates offset without considering rotation and show element in wrong coordinates.

```
function drawLine(a, b, line) {
    var pointA = $(a).offset();
    var pointB = $(b).offset();

    var pointAcenterX = $(a).width() / 2;
    var pointAcenterY = $(a).height() / 2;
    var pointBcenterX = $(b).width() / 2;
    var pointBcenterY = $(b).height() / 2;
    var angle = Math.atan2(pointB.top - pointA.top, pointB.left - pointA.left) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var distance = lineDistance(pointA.left, pointA.top, pointB.left, pointB.top);

    distance = ((distance / image.w) * 100).toFixed(2);

    $(line).css('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)');
    $(line).css('width', distance + '%');

    if(pointB.left < pointA.left) {
        if(pointB.top < pointA.top) {
            $(line).offset({top: pointB.top + pointBcenterY, left: pointB.left + pointBcenterX});
        } else {
            $(line).offset({top: pointA.top + pointBcenterY, left: pointB.left + pointBcenterX});
            console.log(pointA.top + pointBcenterY, pointB.left + pointBcenterX);
        }
    } else {
        if(pointB.top < pointA.top) {
            $(line).offset({top: pointB.top + pointAcenterY, left: pointA.left + pointAcenterX});
        } else {
            $(line).offset({top: pointA.top + pointAcenterY, left: pointA.left + pointAcenterX});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example to replicate the problem

Comment: Added code. As you can see, I rotate line, and then call "offset" function. It works fine in Chrome and FF, but in Safari like this http://joxi.ru/ZrJV37h1EeBQrj . This line not in right position (only in safari)